# I'm having trouble installing rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've gone through hours of tutorials and stackoverflow articles and still haven't found a solution.

Ruby is installed and it works fine.

I ran the command `gem install rails` and it went through the gem installation process; I watched as my `C:\ruby\lib\ruby\gems\2.4.0\gems` directory was updated with rails dependencies. The funny thing is I don't actually see a gem called rails? I only see `rails-dom-testing-2.0.3` and `rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3`

I close the terminal and reopened and it doesn't recognize the `rails` command at all.

I checked that my PATH `c:/ruby/bin` matched the executable directory listed in the command `gem environment`.

Still no dice.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: To install rails, you need to give command `gem install rails` not `install gem rails`. Try doing this.

Comment: typo, that's what I did.

Comment: To clarify, then: (1) You typed `gem install rails`. (2) The installation succeeded. If you type `gem list`, then this includes `"rails"`. (3) Running commands like `ruby` and `gem` work fine. (4) If you run the command `rails`, then you see "command not found". Is everything I said above correct?

Comment: stupid error, rails never actually installed correctly because I didn't install mingw/msys. I got it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with msys/mingw, I didn't have them installed so rails was failing to install.